# What is wrong in below code?

Tags: python

Program to find whether the given number is present in given list of numbers in python.
What is wrong in below code? It never prints "number is present".

```
import sys

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
each = 1
s = raw_input("eneter a number ")

for each in range(0,len(a)):
    if s == a[each]:
        print "number is present"
        sys.exit()
    elif each == len(a):
        print "not present"
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: What are the `''` in `elif each == len(a):''`?

Comment: Why do you say something is wrong? Do not answer in comments, but in the question, using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51780524/edit) feature.

Comment: why did you initialise each=1 ? What is the use in that?

Comment: you can just check `if int(s) in a:` to see if it is in the list.

Comment: @Bernhard it worked thanks :)

Comment: Somewhat unrelated but you seem to be learning python. You really want to learn python3 instead of python2 as it will [retire soon](https://pythonclock.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You can write your code in this way:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
s = int(raw_input("enter a number "))
if s in a:
    print "number is present"
else:
    print "not present"
```

Comment: An additional hint explaining, that the string returned by `raw_input()` will never match the integers given in list `a` would complete this answer.